# Por que no me cuenta las vocales?

Tags: java, bucle-for

mi problema va de hacer un codigo en el cual detecte si una palabra tiene vocales  y si las tiene que las cuente, el problema es que el contador me arroja un 0.

este es mi codigo:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        char [] vocales = {'a','e','i','o','u'};
        String palabra = "La lluvia en Sevilla es una maravillal";
        int contador = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i<palabra.length();i++){
            if(vocales.equals(palabra.charAt(i))){
                contador++;
            }else{
                System.out.print(".");
            }
        }
                    System.out.println(contador);

    }
    
}
```

Comment: equals creo que sólo existe para `Character`, no para la primitiva `char`, menos para un array de `char`. Este código compila? Igual, si tienes un array de `char`, en ninguna parte le dices que compare una posición de `vocales` con `palabra.charAt(i)` y java no tiene cómo saber que quieres comparar cada elemento del array con el carácter...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En primer lugar, te estás complicando declarando para la verificación un array de `char`. Puedes simplemente declarar un `String` que contenga las vocales y luego comparar cada carácter usando `indexOf()`.

Aquí he cubierto también la posibilidad de vocales en mayúscula y puede haber casos más complicados, como palabras con acentos. Para algo más avanzado es mejor que implementes [la API de Normalización](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/text/normalizerapi.html).

#### Código

```
public static void main(String args[])
{

    String vocales = "aeiouAEIOU";
    String palabra = "LA lluvia en Sevilla es una maravillal";
    int contador = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i<palabra.length();i++){
        if(vocales.indexOf(palabra.charAt(i))!= -1){
            contador++;
        }else{
            System.out.print(".");      
        }
    }
    System.out.println(contador);
}
```

**Salida:**

```
.......................15
```

Nótese que puse una `A` a propósito en la cadena.

Answer (score 1):

No cuenta por que en este apartado estas tratando el array vocales como un `String` es decir estas condicionando que si `"aeiou"` es igual a la primer valor de la palabra aumente el contador esto nunca se dara

```
if(vocales.equals(palabra.charAt(i)))
```

lo que debes hacer es que al igual que recorres la palabra debes hacer lo mismo con el array vocales para que cuentes todas las `a` que aparezcan `e` `i` ... independientemente

```
char [] vocales = {'a','e','i','o','u'};
        String palabra = "La lluvia en Sevilla es una maravillal";
        int contador = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i<palabra.length();i++){//recorres la palabra
         for(int j=0;j<vocales.length;j++){//recorres el array vocales
            if(palabra.charAt(i)==vocales[j]){
                contador++;
            }
           }
         }
                    System.out.println(contador);
```

y como te lo comento Alfabravo un primitivo como `char` no usa `equals` si no `==`